# Infinite loop caused by perror scanf through a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe, stdin, infinite-loop

I have been writing a c program which pipes data from one file to the next however it has been infinite looping.

What i have discovered so far. The infinite loop is caused on file c1.c where perror (or stderr) skips the scanf. If scanf does work. The program infinite loops further down the track printing out the perror even though it is past that section!

My code is below

controller.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int ac, char**av)
{
int pipez[2];
int piped[2];
int status;
pid_t pid;

if (pipe (pipez) == -1){
perror("could not make pipe");
return 1;
}

if ((pid = fork()) == -1){
perror("fork");
return 1;
}

if(pid == 0){
close(pipez[1]);
dup2(pipez[0],0);
close(pipez[0]);
execvp("./c1",av);
perror("demo);
_exit(1);
}
else{
close(pipez[0]);
dup2(pipez[1],1);
close(pipez[1]);
execvp("./c2",av);
perror("demo");
exit(1);
}

waitpid(pid,&status,0);
if(WIFEXITED(status)){
printf("[%d] TERMINATED (Status: %d)\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
}

if(pipe (piped) == -1){
perror("could not make pipe");
return 1;
}

if((pid = fork()) == -1){
perror("fork");
return 1;
}

if (pid == 0){
close(piped[1]);
dup2(piped[0],0);
close(piped[0]);
execvp("./c2", av);
perror("demo");
_exit(1);
}
else{
close(piped[0]);
dup2(piped(piped[1],1);
close(piped[1]);
execvp("./c3",av);
perror("demo");
exit(1);
}

waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
if (WIFEXITED(status)){
printf("[%d] TERMINATED (Status: %d)\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
}

return 0;
}
```

c1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

//This program is causing infinite loop, tried fflush and fgets and scanf
// It will run independently but will loop via the pipe

int main(int a, char**av){
char store[BUFSIZE];
memset(store, '\0', sizeof(store));
while(strcmp(store, "exit!") != 0){

perror("Please enter next line of input (type 'exit!' to stop) \n"); //This repeats itself infinitely
fgets(store, BUFSIZE, stdin);
printf("%s",store); // This also repeats itself dependant on where i put 
//fflush or another printf. Repeated outputs occur in blocks
}

return 0;
}
```

c2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

char *strlwr(char *str);

int main(int ac, char**av){
char store[BUFSIZE];

while(strcmp(store, "exit!") != 0){
scanf("%s", store);
printf("%s", strlwr(store));
}

return 0;
}

char *strlwr(char *str){
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)str;

while(*p){
*p = tolower((unsigned char)*p);
p++;
}

return str;

}
```

c3.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

int main(int ac, char**av){
char store[BUFSIZE];
int n = 0;

while(strcmp(store, "exit!") != 0{
scanf("%s",store);
printf("Line %d: %s\n",n,store);
n++;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memset(store, '/0', sizeof(store));` ----> `memset(store, '\0', sizeof(store));`

Comment: Thanks LPs, I had that in the code to begin with but i must of mistyped it in the post. I have edited it now thanks again!

Comment: Note that `perror()` is intended to print an error message on standard error based on the value of `errno` — it is not a general purpose prompting function.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, i used perror because of the pipe, using a function that used stdout would simply send it to the next program/file.  i will however look for alternatives as the program is still mass printing the perror & outputs

Comment: The normal alternative is just `fprintf(stderr, …)`.

Comment: Yeah i gave that a roll, still no luck =(

Comment: Indentation/formatting....

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` leaves `'\n'` char in the `store` buffer so, easiest fix is to add `'\n'` to the compared string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

//This program is causing infinite loop, tried fflush and fgets and scanf
// It will run independently but will loop via the pipe

int main(int a, char**av)
{
    char store[BUFSIZE];
    memset(store, '\0', sizeof(store));
    while (strcmp(store, "exit!\n") != 0)
    {

        perror("Please enter next line of input (type 'exit!' to stop) \n"); //This repeats itself infinitely
        fgets(store, BUFSIZE, stdin);
        printf("%s", store); // This also repeats itself dependant on where i put
                             // fflush or another printf. Repeated outputs occur in blocks
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, as you can see, init value '/0' is not acceptable; it must be '\0'. Your compiler is probably telling you something like

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:242:16: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  memset(store, '/0', sizeof(store));
                ^
```

BTW `memset`, in this case is useless because `fgets` does all the job, but anyway, if you want you buffer set to nul, just declare:

```
char store[BUFSIZE] = {0};
```

Best solution using `fgets` is (obviously) always manage the newline left:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

//This program is causing infinite loop, tried fflush and fgets and scanf
// It will run independently but will loop via the pipe

int main(void)
{
    char store[BUFSIZE] = {0};
    char *pos;
    while (strcmp(store, "exit!") != 0)
    {

        perror("Please enter next line of input (type 'exit!' to stop) \n"); //This repeats itself infinitely
        fgets(store, BUFSIZE, stdin);

        if ((pos = strchr(store, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "String too long!\n");

        printf("%s", store); // This also repeats itself dependant on where i put
                             // fflush or another printf. Repeated outputs occur in blocks
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are faster then my spell checker ;) Thx

Comment: Hi guys, still no luck. the fgets allows me to type input now but when i type exit! the problem occurs again. If i add "exit\n" to c2 the issue stops but it just keeps asking for input and doesnt exit the loop. I have added the suggested code. maybe this is an issue with the pipe?

Comment: @rowboat as you can see [HERE](http://ideone.com/qbLXcV) the code I posted works like a charm

Comment: The individual program c1.c works yes, but when placed through the pipe it outputs repetitive lines such as the perror and the contents of store, im thinking its either a buffer overflow or something similar. A couple of things i noted while i was testing. c1.c exits it's loop after it's first call, even if exit! isnt typed. another thing im thinking is the program may be incorrectly piped.